# IE9 issue CollectionView tagName table with itemViewClass which is CollectionView tagName tr

Tags: ember.js

I have a `CollectionView` which its `itemViewClass` is also a `CollectionView`.  The outer `CollectionView` is of `tagName` "table" while the inner is "tr".  The problem is that this type of view works in all browsers except IE9.

Here is a jsbin with an example http://jsbin.com/iqokor/5/edit.

I believe it has something to do with the fact that a `tbody` is not being wrapped around the inner `CollectionView`'s rendered content. Does anyone have any suggestions so that I can accomplish this type of view and that it works in all browsers.  Keep in mind that my underlying content array looks like this ...

```
[['a','b'],['a1','b1'],['a2','b2']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2018) on github is the cause of your problems.  There is a problem with the `innerHTML` property on IE that is causing the rendering issues, especially for tables.

[This pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2166) fixes the issue for IE, but hasn't been merged yet.